# Difference in security of key generation for Armory Wallet vs BIP32

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

I have been studying Armory’s key derivation path vs BIP 32 (thanks Pieter!) and am trying to determine if there is any increased security with BIP 32 or strictly convenience gains. If the entropy involved in both is equivalent, are all modern wallets essentially using Alan Reiner’ design?